# What would cause continuous electron buildup on the ground during a thunderstorm?

Tags: electrostatics, weather

I realize that the triboelectric phenomena going on during thunderstorms is not well understood (as pointed out by [xkcd here](https://xkcd.com/1867/)).  However, on June 16 I witnessed behavior that I had never before seen during a storm, and I was wondering what was known about it.  Specifically, there was a consistent pattern of negative charge building up on the ground, over a large area and a substantial period of time, which was periodically dissipated by very unusual ground-to-cloud lightning.

This happened starting at about 9:20 p.m., northeast of Columbia, South Carolina (around $34.118^{\circ}$ north, $80.858^{\circ}$ west).  I first noticed that the thunderstorm around me (I was near the edge) featured the most extensive and horizontal cloud-to-cloud lightning I had ever seen.  Intrigued, I pulled my car over in a dark place where I had a good view in all directions and watched for about forty minutes.

Every couple minutes, there would be an upstroke from the somewhere on the ground.  Ground-to-cloud lightning is not that uncommon, and I had seen it before, but this was unusual in several different ways:

- All the lightning strikes I saw around me were ground to cloud; there were none of the usual downward strokes.
- The upstrokes rose initially looked like a many-trunked tree.  Around the origin point, the upstrokes looked rather like this.

[image: Ground-to-cloud lightning]

- However, rather than terminating, as in the picture, the branches of the upward bolt all turned sideways when they reached the bottom of the bank of thunderheads.  So the upstroke was continued by the extensive cloud-to-cloud lightning that I had first noticed.  When it reached the bottom of the cloud layer, the lightning would fork and run out to the sides, equalizing the potentials along the bottoms of all the cloud layer.  The sideways strokes looked rather like this, only they were even more extensive, with each upward stroke leading to a web of cloud-to-cloud lightning that covered as much as a third of my horizon.

[image: Cloud-to-cloud lightning]

- Unlike ground-to-cloud and cloud-to-cloud lightning I had seen before, which were generally sporadic phenomena, this kept on happening, fifteen or twenty times, every couple of minutes while I watched.
- The area from which the upstrokes originated was fairly large.  Based on the distances to the strokes, which came from three of the four cardinal directions relative to my observation position, the area of ground that was being negatively charged was several square miles in area.  It was not a very-small-scale anomaly.

So, is it known what could cause this kind of unusual thunderstorm?

Comment: Have you considered asking also/instead at [earthscience.se]?